# Different where conditions through if and else in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using the following query:

```
if(@usertype = 'all')
begin
    select * 
    from tbllogin a 
    left join tblUserType_Master b on a.typeid = b.id 
    where (b.user_type = 'agent' or b.user_type = 'branch') ; 
end
else if(@usertype = 'branch')
begin
    select * 
    from tbllogin a 
    left join tblUserType_Master b on a.typeid = b.id 
    where b.user_type = 'branch' ; 
end
else if(@usertype = 'agent')
begin
    select * 
    from tbllogin a 
    left join tblUserType_Master b on a.typeid = b.id 
    where b.user_type = 'agent' ; 
end
```

This works perfectly fine but the only difference between the three queries is the where condition. Is there any way that I can store the value of where condition in a variable and just add it to the common part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a variable with the value as far as I can see. Why not simply use it:

```
select
    *
from
    tbllogin a
    left join tblUserType_Master b on a.typeid=b.id
where
    b.user_type = @usertype or (@usertype='all' and b.usertype in ('branch','agent'))
```

I would also like to point out a couple of things: you are using left joins but comparing to the right-side table, which will eliminate all records from the ***tbllogin*** that do not have a match in the ***tblUserType_Master*** anyway.

You can do the following instead, it will surely perform better:

```
select
    *
from
    tbllogin a
    inner join tblUserType_Master b on a.typeid=b.id
where
    b.user_type = @usertype or (@usertype='all' and b.usertype in ('branch','agent'))
```

Also, I strongly recommend against using select *, listing the columns explicitly is a recommended path.

Comment: I used b.user_type='agent' or b.user_type='branch' in @usertype='all' as there are three more types of user.This would work for branch and agent but not all.

Comment: @rexroxm I've adjusted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use CASE Statement in WHERE Clause to get your result :

SELECT * FROM tbllogin a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblUserType_Master b ON a.typeid=b.id 
WHERE ( @usertype='all' AND b.user_type IN ('agent','branch') ) OR 
      b.user_type = CASE WHEN @usertype='branch' THEN 'branch' 
                         WHEN @usertype='agent' THEN 'agent' END
```

Comment: it would work for branch and agent but in case of all there are three more user types. That's why in @usertype='all'  i have used b.user_type='agent' or b.user_type='branch'.

Comment: @rexroxm,If @usertype='all' means b.user_type = CASE WHEN @usertype='all' THEN b.user_type,This query give all user types

Comment: Exactly and i want b.user_type='agent' or b.user_type='branch' when @usertype='all'